# How to handle more than one zustand store into the browser devtools

Tags: reactjs, devtools, zustand

I am new to Zustand, but right away I've created two stores and I want to be able to see the behavior of both on the browser devtools.

Using

```
import {devtools} from 'zustand/middleware'
```

allowed me to have just one store at a time. I tried `import {devtools} from '@pavlobu/zustand/middleware'` and nothing
also zukeeper and nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use it in the following way:

```
const Store1 = create(devtools((set) => ..., { name, store: storeName1 }))
const store2 = create(devtools((set) => ..., { name, store: storeName2 }))
```

Or you can combine both stores like this:

```
const useStore = create(
  devtools((...a) => ({
    ...createStoreSlice1(...a),
    ...createStoreSlice2(...a)
  }))
);
```

I suggest you also read this article About Slices Pattern in Zustand:
https://docs.pmnd.rs/zustand/guides/slices-pattern

Comment: I followed your suggestions, liked the second one, all is working nice and now I am able to watch the values on redux devtools. thanks